# liquibase installation on centos, JNI error

Tags: java, linux, centos, java-native-interface, liquibase

I installed java on my CentOS 6.9:

```
  [root@sample liquibase-3.6.2-bin.z]# java -version
  openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

then I tried to run liquibase.jar but i got this error:

```
  [root@sample liquibase-3.6.2-bin.z]# ll
  total 11368
  drwxrwxrwx. 2 db2inst1 db2iadm1    4096 Dec 17 13:10 lib
 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1   11358 Jul  3 23:27 LICENSE.txt
 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1    1251 Jul  3 23:27 liquibase
 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1     884 Jul  3 23:27 liquibase.bat
 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1 2167086 Jul  3 23:30 liquibase.jar
 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1    7174 Jul  3 23:27 liquibase.spec
 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 db2inst1 db2iadm1    3046 Jul  3 23:27 README.txt
 drwxrwxrwx. 6 db2inst1 db2iadm1    4096 Dec 17 13:10 sdk
 [root@sample liquibase-3.6.2-bin.z]# java -jar liquibase.jar
 Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try 
 again
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
 ch/qos/logback/core/filter/Filter
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at 
    sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    ch.qos.logback.core.filter.Filter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
    [root@sampleliquibase-3.6.2-bin.z]#
```

what shoul I do? am i missing something?how can I find these classes?

Comment: It seems like you just downloaded the liquibase jar file while instead you need the `bin.zip` file or the `tar.gz`file. They will have a `lib` folder inside which contains the `logback` jar file with the classes.

Answer (score 1):

The error is a general missing class error, and not a JNI error. The error is misleading as it indicates the wrong source of the problem.

Those classes are in the `lib/` directory. There is a dos bat file for launching it. The equivalent on unix is something like:

```
#!/bin/bash -p

for main in liquibase*.jar; do
    cp=$main
done

for i in lib/*.jar; do
    [[ -f $i ]] && cp=$cp:$i
done
java -classpath $cp liquibase.integration.commandline.Main "$@"
```

however, this yields the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
```

which indicates another missing library - simple logging for java.

To address this problem. You need a copy of slf4j. Downloading the [latest binary zip](https://www.slf4j.org/download.html), and extracting the api file - it'll be called `sl4j-api-<version>.jar` into the `lib` directory of liquibase should allow you to get a little bit further.

Comment: Unfortunately, *didn't work* doesn't really help in this context. Are you still seeing the same error (about missing `ch/qos/logback/core/filter/Filter`, or is it the error in relation to the missing `org/slf4j/LoggerFactory`? or is it some other error?

Comment: How did you launch it in that case? The code I supplied should be placed in a `liquibase.sh` script at the root of the liquibase tree, and then run as `./liquibase.sh`.